# Sulu with Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, sulu

I would like to know that how can I install the Sulu with Symfony 4. I'm following the document [here](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/getting-started.html) and run the command

```
composer create-project sulu/sulu-minimal sulu -n
```

So I got the Sulu mininal (v1.6.25) installed with the Symfony v3.4.23.

Comment: Sulu may want to keep using a LTS version of Symfony, take a look at symfony release policy :  https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html

Comment: I checked the package and the version 2 of Sulu wich has support for Symfony 4 is in alpha. The version 1.6.25 only uses Symfony 3.4

Comment: Hi @Ryu any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Sulu uses Symfony 3.4. According to [this](https://blog.sulu.io/sulu-2-0-0-alpha4-released) blog post and the [changelog](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/releases/tag/2.0.0-alpha4) they updated to Symfony 4 in the 2.0.0-alpha4 version. If you need it for the production then don't use it. For development purposes you can install the newest alpha version with the following command:

`composer create-project sulu/sulu-minimal sulu "2.0.0-alpha5" -n`

Comment: The end of the result I got
`Writing lock file
.
> @php bin/adminconsole cache:clear

 [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:                               

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
                                                                               
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for u  
  ser 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)                                  
.
Script @php bin/adminconsole cache:clear handling the sulu-auto-scripts event returned with error code 1`

Any suggestion? Please advice.